# How would companies capitalize on the existence of magic, forcing the little peopel to rise against them?

Tags: society, magic, economy, politics

I wanted to combine "Shadowrun" - "industrial espionage runs rampant in a near-future setting. A "Shadowrun" is successful data theft or physical break-in at a rival corporation or organization – is one of the main tools employed by both corporate rivals and underworld figures..." - with dark fantasy. But I have a hard time coming up with reasonable ways to combine the two.

In short, assuming that magic exists in a fictional dark fantasy world, how could companies (or the equivalent in a fantasy setting) capitalize on the existence of magic in such a way that it would force the little people to rise against them just like deckers/hackers do in cyberpunk settings?

Comment: Isn't this what *the author* is supposed to imagine? VTC as fundamentally opinion based. For example: they might patent the most interesting spells; use magic to manipulate the stock exchange; magically influence the decisions of regulators; employ corrupt wizards to influence the buying decisions of consumers; obtain a monopoly on the use of magical minions as flexible assembly robots; have corrupt legislators make the use of magic illegal for anybody who is not on the schedule of approved corporations; imbue their products with magic which makes them fail two days after warranty ends...

Comment: Ultimately companies will capitalize on magic the same way they do every other human talent, by using it to provide products and services for which there is a market. One of the key insights of urban fantasy is that being good at magic is not inherently different from being good at math, or baseball, or bodyguarding, or any of countless other professions.

Comment: Shadowrun (the game) has an extremely dystopian background. The player characters usually are not revolutionaries, but thieves and killers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specifically in the Shadowrun Setting

**Aztechnology's** founders and upper ranks consist of practitioners who never gave up on magic, kept their relationships with the spirits up-to-date, and kept their traditions alive. When magic came back as capably as technology, this group of individuals was part of the magical Manhattan Project. As one of a very small nuclear-equivalent club, they have a great deal of military clout.

Aztlan is called a corporate-controlled country (controlled by Aztechnology) in some of the Shadowrun material. In our time, we'd say it's a government-controlled company. I think the difference is semantic : the government and the corporation overlap significantly.

Much as the U.S. recruited German rocket scientists after the war, Aztechnology used it's sudden political, military might and cultural allure to pull the most brilliant minds from the world. They have shrewdly invested in building up intellectual and legal might (as a corporation among corporations) to add to their military, and political CV.

**Mitzuhama**, as the outsider looking in to the magical world took advantage of ignorance in the patent system to internationally legally lock down every herbal remedy, chant, script, scripture, tome, and artifact. The ties between Mitzuhama's upper echelons and the Japanese help give military and political support to Mitzuhama's novel legal theories (which give them rights to all these magical curiosities). They are also investing heavily in understanding all of the information they've locked down, sifting out the valuable stuff from the dross.

**Wuxing** is the only other AAA megacorporation in the Shadowrun setting to be investing in magic. The Chinese-owned megacorporation's approach to magic is halfway between Aztechnology's and Mitzuhama's. Wuxing has access to a large cultural pool that has not completely abandoned their traditional practices.

The other 7 AAA megacorporations in the Shadowrun setting haven't made magic a priority.

### How Does It Contribute to Dystopia?

This remains dystopia if none of these corporations are behaving with ideals that improve the world. If Aztechnology does not challenge Mitzuhama's patent overreach, but negotiates backroom trades instead. If Mitzuhama refuses to let useful magic into the open market, but instead keeps a ideas it has not yet figured out how to productize from doing any good for anyone (even persecuting the "traditional" practicitioners who owned these things.